# Loop through the rows of a two column WPF datagrid and form a list collection with the elements

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

I am creating an application in which i created a list collection and successfully binded it to a datagrid. The problem I am having is to pull data back from the datagrid and use it to form the elements of the same list collection when a user clicks the SAVE button after making changes to the datagrid.
Thanks in advance.

The XAML is shown below:

```
<Grid Background="CornflowerBlue">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="530" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="gridBeveragesAndJuices" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="573"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Cyan" RowBackground="#FF12AD12" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Cyan" Foreground="Cyan" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" 
              EnableRowVirtualization="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="DodgerBlue" FontSize="13">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DodgerBlue" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="287" Header="                        ITEMS"
                       Binding="{Binding Path=ITEMS8, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" x:Name="ItemsColumn" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="286" Header="                        PRICE"
                       Binding="{Binding Path=PRICE8, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" x:Name="PriceColumn"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,578,0,0" Name="btnCancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <Button Content="Save" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,578,0,0" Name="btnSave" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnSave_Click" />
    <Button Content="Exit" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="444,578,0,0" Name="btnExit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />


</Grid>
```

And below is the code behind:

```
public partial class BeveragesAndJuices : Window
{
    public BeveragesAndJuices()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gridBeveragesAndJuices.ItemsSource = Source8;
    }

    public class Values8 
    {
        public string ITEMS8 { get; set; }
        public decimal PRICE8 { get; set; }
    }


    public List<Values8> Source8 = new List<Values8> 
    {
        new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Lacasera ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Cran-Orange Chiller ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Festive Fruity Flavored Milk  ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
        new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Homemade Iced Coffee ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Lemon Cucumber Seltzer " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Fizzy Water ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
        new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Haunted (Black Cauldron) Punch  " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Lemon Ginger Iced Green Tea " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Orange Creamsicle Shake " , PRICE8 = 290}, 
        new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Blueberry Blast Smoothie ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Shamrock Milk Mixer " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Pomegranate Punch  ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
        new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="anned Milo " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Viju Milk " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "5 Alive ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
        new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Cherry Vanilla Smoothie  " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Boysenberry-Banana Blast ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Vanilla Iced Mochaccino  ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
        new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Choco-Nana Milk Mixer " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Fresh Fruit Pudding Milk Mixer ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Luscious Licuado  " , PRICE8 = 290}, 
        new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Frosty Pine-Orange Yogurt Smoothie ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Mocha-ccino Freeze ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Lite Iced Mocha " , PRICE8 = 290}, 
        new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Nectarine Whirl " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Strawberries and Cream Smoothie  " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Strawberry Light Lemonade " , PRICE8 = 290}
    };

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //clear the elements of the source  
        Source8.Clear();

        //get the items on the datagrid and use them to form new elements of the 
        //Source8

        foreach(DataGridRow Row in gridBeveragesAndJuices)
        {
            //this where am stuck, foreach flags an error
            //that DataGridRow does not have a definition for GetEnumerator
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SO supports also use of small letters in the title. SO audience doesn't like shrieking people.

Comment: -1 for all caps. Sorry, it's too much for an empty stomach

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to rebuild Source8 because your TwoWayBinding for ITEMS8 and PRICE8 does the job. The values are already up to date. Even if you add a new `Row` to the `DataGrid` Source8 will immediately show a new entry.

Use your Save-Button to serialize the Source8, it is the state of your `DataGrid`.

Comment: Thanks LPL for the idea. Please explain this serialization with a code sample, it's not yet known to me.

Comment: Take a look at [C# Tutorial - XML Serialization](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) or [Introducing XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [Binary Serialization and Deserialization in C#](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=8802451).

Answer (score 0):

I would change up you code a bit and bind.   Create the list should not really be a public property as it will new the list each time - the = new is not meant to be consumed externally.

```
   private List<> source8 = new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Lacasera ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Cran-Orange Chiller ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Festive Fruity Flavored Milk  ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
    new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Homemade Iced Coffee ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Lemon Cucumber Seltzer " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Fizzy Water ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
    new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Haunted (Black Cauldron) Punch  " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Lemon Ginger Iced Green Tea " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Orange Creamsicle Shake " , PRICE8 = 290}, 
    new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Blueberry Blast Smoothie ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Shamrock Milk Mixer " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Pomegranate Punch  ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
    new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="anned Milo " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Viju Milk " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "5 Alive ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
    new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Cherry Vanilla Smoothie  " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Boysenberry-Banana Blast ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Vanilla Iced Mochaccino  ", PRICE8 = 290}, 
    new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Choco-Nana Milk Mixer " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Fresh Fruit Pudding Milk Mixer ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Luscious Licuado  " , PRICE8 = 290}, 
    new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Frosty Pine-Orange Yogurt Smoothie ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 = "Mocha-ccino Freeze ", PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Lite Iced Mocha " , PRICE8 = 290}, 
    new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Nectarine Whirl " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Strawberries and Cream Smoothie  " , PRICE8 = 290}, new Values8(){ITEMS8 ="Strawberry Light Lemonade " , PRICE8 = 290};

public BeveragesAndJuices()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gridBeveragesAndJuices.ItemsSource = Source8;  // move this to XAML Binding
}

public class Values8 
{
    public string ITEMS8 
    { 
        get; 
        set
        {
             Debug.WriteLine(value);
             // this is where you do the update
        } 
    }
    public decimal PRICE8 { get; set; }
}


public List<Values8> Source8
{
    get { return source8; }

}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //clear the elements of the source  
    //Source8.Clear(); for sure you don't want to do this  !

    //get the items on the datagrid and use them to form new elements of the 
    //Source8

    // do this is the set
    //foreach(DataGridRow Row in gridBeveragesAndJuices)
    //{
        //this where am stuck, foreach flags an error
        //that DataGridRow does not have a definition for GetEnumerator
    //}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. how am i going to save the changes on the datagrid to Source8 when the SAVE button is clicked? i also want the user to be able to add new elements to Source8 via the datagrid.

Comment: Since it is bound changes to the DataGrid do update Source8.   See the debug statement.